# Find an element in the nearest cell (td) using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, siblings

Below is a function to convert value **`A`** when value **`B`** is entered and vice versa.

I am trying to work out an efficient way to target **only** the nearest matching input using **javascript** or **jQuery**.

I've tried jQuery [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [prev](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

### QUESTION

Using Javascript what is an efficient way to target an element in an adjacent cell without the search function becoming convoluted?

---

### DEMO

**HTML**

```
<td><input class="A" value="0" OnChange="convertA(this.id, this.value);"/></td>
<td><input class="B" value="0" OnChange="convertB(this.id, this.value);"/></td>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function convertA(id, value) {
    $('.B').val(value * 2);
}
function convertB(id, value) {
    $('.A').val(value / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery use it for event handles as well

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //use jQuery event handlers
  $('.A').change(function() {
    //find the element in the same row and update
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.B').val((this.value / 2) || 0)
  });
  $('.B').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.A').val((this.value * 2) || 0)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="A" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="B" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="A" value="0" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="B" value="0" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

using jquery only

```
$("input").change(function() {
    var n = this.value;
    if ($(this).hasClass("B")) {
        n = this.value / 2;
    } else {
        n = this.value * 2;
    }
    $(this).closest("td").siblings().find("input").val(n);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0sL8vzL5/5/)

*

Comment: Note that you've completely changed the logic the OP originally had.

Comment: How will this find the adjacent cell ? Please Dont answer if have no Idea about it...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes you are correct. Changed my code as per Op's logic.

Comment: @DipeshRana what do you mean?

Comment: @DipeshRana did you even check the fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is because the `this` keyword does not reference the element that raised the event when you attach your event handlers via attributes. You can get around this by attaching your events in JS instead.

You can then use `closest()` to find the parent `tr` element, and `find()` the related `input` within that row. Try this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input class="A" value="0" /></td>
    <td><input class="B" value="0" /></td>
</tr>
```

```js
$('.A').change(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = this.value;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.B').val(value * 2);
});

$('.B').change(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    var value = this.value;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.A').val(value / 2);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0sL8vzL5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".A").on("input", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input.B").val(eval($(this).val()*2));
    });
    $(".B").on("input", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input.A").val(eval($(this).val()/2));
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0sL8vzL5/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".A, .B").on("keyup", function(){
    $(this).hasClass("A") ? $(this).closest("tr").find(".B").val(this.value * 2) : 
                            $(this).closest("tr").find(".A").val(this.value / 2);
});
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0sL8vzL5/8/)

Better to use more specific class names/identifiers though.

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient way to target an element in an adjacent cell is using `.next()` method...

Comment: Can you demonstrate an example?

Comment: $(this).next('td input').val(n);

Comment: There is no 'next' element for the input.

Comment: Its just an demo of  how .next() is used

Comment: Of course OP will use it as $(this).parent('td').next('td input').val(n)

Comment: Then why not put this in your answer? It will get a better response from viewers.

Comment: You have changed your answer

Comment: i havent changed the jquery part. $(this).closest("td").siblings().find("input").val(this.value * 2); was the first one.. and your question was "How will this find the adjacent cell ?"

Comment: Also .parent('td') is meaningless.  It will only return the immediate parent only.. you just need to use .parent()

Comment: Both will do the same job

Comment: passing argument to "parent()" is meaningless.. Either you need to use closest() or parents()..

Comment: You can complaint with Jquery Developers because they have given a option to pass argument in .parent()